# Create Field Dependency in Frontend Form

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, forms

I have 2 select attributes in frontend `phone model` and `phone brand`.
I want these two attributes to be dependant i.e. If suppose I click on "Apple" all the phone models under "Apple" brand category should come in the second select option. All the data comes from backend. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you give a go at JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the `SelectUpdater` JavaScript that is defined in `js/mage/adminhtml/form.js`

*I know this is only in the admin section but you should be able to take this and make it work in the front end.*

Basically what you need is a snippet of code linking the two selects together and the mappings  between the two select's values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var updater = new SelectUpdater(
        "select1", // id of first select
        "select2", // id of second select
        "none", // defaults
        "none", // defaults
        <?php echo $this->helper('some_helper')->getConfigInJsonFormat() ?>, // values in json format
        false
    );
    updater.update();
</script>
```

The values are returned in json format should be built from a helper and replaced into the html string just before being returned. The easiest way to build the values is to create an array of the following format.

```
array(
    'first_select_value1' => array(
        'second_select_value1' => 'second_select_text1',
        'second_select_value2' => 'second_select_text2',
    ),
    'first_select_value2' => array(
        'second_select_value3' => 'second_select_text3',
        'second_select_value4' => 'second_select_text4',
    )
)
```